# How to create a column by iteration on another column?

Tags: python

I have a column with values and I would like to create a new column where each a word will be associated with each value interval.

For example:
If in column B, value range from 0-10, Those values will output Bad in the new column. If 11 to 20, output will be moderate.
If over 20, output will be excellent.

I basically need an iteration on a column and create a new column with predetermined segmentation words.
Issue im currently running into, im apparently missing colon after x=10 but im not:

```
def labels(x):
    '''Flag Function'''
    if x = 10:
        return 'a'
    elif x <= 12:
        return 'b'
    elif x <= 14:
        return "c"
    elif x <= 18:
        return 'd'
    elif x <= 20:
        return 'e'
```

Comment: What format is the data in?

Comment: What is a column in this case? What have you tried? Do you have an example of the input data?

Comment: Let's take a look at your current code

Comment: @AlexTănăsescu edited my code

Comment: should be if x == 10:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with pandas, by example:

```
import pandas as pd
def quote(x):
    if x <= 10.0:
        return 'a'
    elif x <= 12.0:
        return 'b'
    elif x <= 14.0:
        return 'c'
    elif x <= 18.0:
        return 'd'
    elif x <= 20.0:
        return 'e'
    else:
        return 'f'

dat = {'column_to_iterate': [0.9, 10.0, 10.1, 12.5, 15, 19.6, 22.2],}
df = pd.DataFrame(dat)

df['segment'] = df['column_to_iterate'].map(quote)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   column_to_iterate segment
0                0.9       a
1               10.0       a
2               10.1       b
3               12.5       c
4               15.0       d
5               19.6       e
6               22.2       f
```

Comment: is it normal that its not taking into consideration values with decimal numbers

Comment: Edited. It works for me.  I have python 3.7 on Win10.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign labels with a function then apply it to the numeric values in your column like so:

```
n = list(range(30)) # create df
df = pd.DataFrame(n, columns=['Numbers'])

def labels(x):
    '''Flag Function'''
    if x == 10:
        return 'a'
    elif x <= 12:
        return 'b'
    elif x <= 14:
        return "c"
    elif x <= 18:
        return 'd'
    elif x <= 20:
        return 'e'
    elif x >20:
        return 'f'

df['Flag'] = df['Numbers'].apply(lambda x: labels(x)) # apply flag function

print(df)
```

output:

```
    Numbers Flag
0         0    b
1         1    b
2         2    b
3         3    b
4         4    b
5         5    b
6         6    b
7         7    b
8         8    b
9         9    b
10       10    a
11       11    b
12       12    b
13       13    c
14       14    c
15       15    d
16       16    d
17       17    d
18       18    d
19       19    e
20       20    e
21       21    f
22       22    f
23       23    f
24       24    f
25       25    f
26       26    f
27       27    f
28       28    f
29       29    f
```

Comment: thats exactly what im looking for... why am i getting an error saying colon expected
after i write def labels(x):
    
    if x = 11:

Comment: You have to have colons after each if statement and after any function definition. Probably a typo

Comment: ive just edited my question to show where its telling im wrong

Comment: You need a `==` for `x = 10` in python `=` is an assignment operator. Python is interpreting this as `x = 10` and you trying to apply `if` to it. `==` is for equality

Comment: Now i have another issue saying  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1472, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "<input>", line 39, in <lambda>
  File "<input>", line 3, in labels
TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= int()

Comment: Every time you run this reset your dataframe. See my edit above and you won't get this issue. It is trying to run the lambda function on the flag column after you ran it the first time.,

Comment: You won't have to restart the df every time now. The line I changed with df['flag'] will solve that last issue.